# non-lisp languages with seporate namespaces for variables and functions

Tags: programming-languages

Are there any other languages like Common Lisp or Emacs Lisp that have separate namespaces for variables and functions?

I'm generally interested and the Google results are flooded with non relevant info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, in a sense php can be said to have that. If I understand your question correctly.

For example:

```
$hello="a variable";

function hello() {
    return "a function";
}

echo $hello."\n";
echo hello()."\n";
```

Would print:

```
a variable
a function
```

So both the variable and the function is called hello.